# Ternary operator, looking to use multiple ternary operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this section of the code which is part of the full code that I posted at the bottom,

```js
{
  this.props.program.application_required ||
    this.state.isEnableWaitlist ||
    this.isFree() ? ( <
      button type = "button"
      onClick = { _ => this.manualPayment() }
      style={{
          padding: "10px",
          display: "block",
          marginLeft: "auto",
          marginBottom: 0
        }}>
      {
        this.props.program.application_required ||
        this.state.isEnableWaitlist ?
        "Submit Application" :
          "Confirm Order"
      } </button>
    )
```

I want to separate `this.state.isEnableWaitlist` from the other two `this.props.program.application_required` & `this.isFree()` inside the same if statement so that if `this.state.isEnableWaitlist` it will have it's own onClick function before it hits the second part of the false statement which starts with

```js
: (<>
  <p style = {{
      padding: "20px",
      fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif"
    }}.
```

What is the best way to do it in a ternary operator?

**This is the full code below**

```js
{
  this.props.program.application_required ||
    this.state.isEnableWaitlist ||
    this.props.program.manual_invoices ||
    this.isFree() ? (<> {
        this.props.program.application_required ||
        this.state.isEnableWaitlist ||
        this.isFree() ? ( <
          button type = "button"
          onClick = { _ => this.manualPayment() }
          style = {{
              padding: "10px",
              display: "block",
              marginLeft: "auto",
              marginBottom: 0
            }} >
          {
            this.props.program.application_required ||
            this.state.isEnableWaitlist ?
            "Submit Application" :
              "Confirm Order"
          } </button>
        ) : ( <>
          <p style = {{
              padding: "20px",
              fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif"
            }} >
          <b> {
            this.props.organization
          } </b> opted to collect
          payments manually.After confirming your order {
            " "
          } <b> {
            this.props.organization
          } </b> will contact you to
          discuss next steps & payment options. </p>
          <
            button type = "button"
            onClick = { _ => this.manualPayment() }
            style = {{
                padding: "10px",
                display: "block",
                marginLeft: "auto",
                marginBottom: 0
              }} >
          Confirm Order </button> </>
        )
      } </>
    )
```

Comment: Also you can separate conditions by `()`, `(x1 || x2) && (x3 || x4)`

Comment: In my point of view, ternary statements should be snapshots from a condition true or false. To get a better maintenance and readability to your code why not create a method that has all those conditions you want to test and use in the ternary condition? I think you'll add more meaning to your code and make the next developer happy while reading that code. You can always add whatever you want to the ternary condition but you could be more prone to errors also.

Answer (score -1):

**Falsy values**

```js
[0, "", '', false, null, undefined]
```

**Ternary**

```js
condition ? yes : no;

condition
? 1
: condition2
  ? 1
  : 0
```

**Logical AND**

```
12 && "hello" && null && undefined // return first falsy value
```

**Logical OR**

```js
12 || "hello" || null || undefined // return first truthy value
```

**Nullish coalescing**

```js
0 ?? "hello" // 0
false ?? "hello" // false
```

**Logical nullish assignment**

```js
// Normal
let x = null;
 
if (x === null || x === undefined) {
  x = 12;
}

// Advanced
let x = null;
 
x ??= 12;
```

**Logical OR assignment**

```js
// Normal
let x = false;
 
if (!x) {
  x = 12;
}

// Advanced
let x = false;
 
x ||= 12;
```

**Logical AND assignment**

```js
// Normal
let x = "Truthy value";
 
if (x) {
  x = 12;
}

// Advanced
let x = "Truthy value";
 
x &&= 12;
```

Comment: See persian Docks: https://ditty.ir/posts/js-conditional-operators/XoM25